# Userscript keeps scrolling/snapping to iFrame multiple times, until click trigger is fired

Tags: jquery, userscripts

I made this fairly simple [userscript](https://monkeyguts.com/code.php?id=955) to download videos on gametrailers.com without having to navigate to each page individually (see comments for clarification, because the code is ugly, jQuery, and unreadable):

```
var doIt = function(){
  // Look for video list container 
  var results = $(".line_listing_results");
  // Iterate through each listed video
  results.children().each(function(key, vidElem) { 
     // get url to individual video page
     var url = $(vidElem).find('.thumbnail').attr('href'); 
     // some style for the download button
     var styles = 'width: 4.875em; height: 1.5em; cursor: pointer; background-color: #3a8eb7; color: white; padding: 0.3em; font-size: 1.5em;' 
      // Append a download button to each thumbnail and bind a click
      $(vidElem).append('<a id="dl-'+key+'" style="'+styles+'">Download</a>').click(function(clickElem){ 
       // Create iFrame (problem is here)
       var iframe = $('<iframe src="'+url+'#mod_j8j95m" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe-'+key+'"></iframe>')
       // Insert iFrame
       iframe.appendTo('#dl-'+key)
       // Bind 'onReady' to iFrame 
       $('#iframe-'+key).load(function(iElem){
         // Click the download button
         $('#iframe-'+key).contents().find(".download_button").trigger("click");
       }.bind(this))
    }.bind(this))
  }.bind(this));  
};
$(document).ready(function(){
 doIt();
 })
```

The problem is that the main video page keeps snapping to the iFrame when I include the `#mod_j8j95m` in the url, when I scroll down to click another video/download button. 
The thing I can't explain, is that this happens multiple times (Chrome). So when I scroll down it will snap back to the iFrame in a certain interval (1 or 2 seconds, not clear).

The reason why I'm including the `#mod_j8j95m` is I want to lighten the load on the page, because it is heavy as it is (especially since they embedded a youtube video (which I blocked the frame for with adBlock, which fixes dozens of bogus requests to chromecast, which would slow down the loading of the website to snail-speed)). 
But it seems it actually loads the whole page anyways, just filters out that `id`

So, a couple of questions:

1. Why is it snapping/triggering the `id` multiple times?
2. Is there a way to only load a part of an iFrame? (even just the download button
   would be enough in this case, or just the download `url`)
3. And why does the snapping stop, once the `click` has been fired?

Comment: The overall/main/containing page keeps scrolling?  Is there a hashtag in that page's URL (EG `#iframe-3`, etc.)?  You can also try hiding the iframes with CSS.

Comment: Yes and yes: `#mod_j8j95m` it says it right in the question. When I leave that out, it doesn't scroll. I'm not asking for a solution, but a clarification or explanation as to why. Specifically why it happens multiple times, and why that stops after click has fired...

Comment: Not the iframe URL; the overall page URL is what I asked about.

Comment: No, it's: http://www.gametrailers.com/videos-trailers